# What bolt is a replacement for the front sway bar bolts on a 2004 Subaru WRX wagon?

Tags: subaru, suspension, wrx

In replacing my worn endlinks recently with [lovely Kartboy pieces](http://www2.kartboy.com/x4/product.php?productid=16192&cat=253&page=3), I noticed that I had a seized bolt in one of the rear links. I was able to get a short-term replacement until I order a new Kartboy bolt but I noticed that they do not carry bolts for the wagon fronts.

What are the specs for the front bolt on the sway bar endlink for the 2004 WRX wagon? Is there an easy source for such a part?

Comment: Hmmmm I would think dealer or salvage yard is the best place to get an exact replacement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's an excellent [Subaru parts catalog](http://opposedforces.com/parts/) online. I think [this is the drawing](http://opposedforces.com/parts/impreza/us_g11/type_20/suspension_and_axle/front_suspension/illustration_1/) you want. I'm not sure what you mean by "front" bolt, though -- isn't one directly above the other?

Comment: Sorry, got confused ... front bolts, rear links ... it's fixed now!

Answer (score 2):

The best source is your local dealer. Depending on how good the parts diagrams are, it can be a pain ordering the correct bolt. If you do it online or over the phone, there's a good chance they'll order the wrong one. Go to the parts counter and look at the picture with the parts specialist. Hopefully, the exact bolt is easy enough to point out.

Chances are, they'll have to special order it. If the wrong one comes in, you don't have to worry about shipping back and forth.

There are some *really* bad parts diagrams out there, even in official dealerships.

Comment: Very good advise here about navigating the issue of efficiently locating the correct part.  Very common to have get the wrong part a time or two ...